# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch google api oauth2 to get access token

Tags: google-oauth

Getting following error in my code.

400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}

I don't understand what is wrong. I seemed to be using google api's correctly as defined in their specifications. After creating a installed app in the developer console I got the authorization code from the browser and plugged it in. The redirect_uri was picked from the console. Can anyone point to me what is wrong with the redirect_uri. I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong with that parameter.

```
    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;

    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;

    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.AdExchangeSeller;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.AdExchangeSellerScopes;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.model.AdClients;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.model.AdUnits;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.model.CustomChannels;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.model.SavedReports;

    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.AdExchangeSeller;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.AdExchangeSeller.Reports.Generate;
    import com.google.api.services.adexchangeseller.model.Report;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class Reporting {

    public class AdXReporting {

      private static String AD_CLIENT_ID = "....";

      private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "AdX Installed app product";

      private static final String authorizationCode = "..............";

      private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

      private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

      private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File("adexchangeseller_sample");
      private static void authorize() {

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("client_secrets.json")));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport,
                JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton(AdExchangeSellerScopes.ADEXCHANGE_SELLER_READONLY)
            ).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();


        GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest =
            flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode);

        tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URL);
        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();

        // Store the credential for the user.
        flow.createAndStoreCredential(tokenResponse, AD_CLIENT_ID);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this redirect_uri the same with with the one you using in getting the authorization code?

Answer (score 16):

your pointer was correct.

I was scratching my head for two days on what was wrong.

Apparently the redirect_uri need to match between auth and token requests.

The redirect_uri_mismatch will be thrown if it is not.

The documentation for google api says to use the *redirect_uri* from the *developer-console*.
However, the url that they auto-generate, to paste in the browser, doesn't do that, and uses a *localhost + port* url that is different.
This was fundamental source of problem.

If you take the auth url, that they asked you to cut and paste in browser, and plug in the correct *redirect_uri* "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" from the console and get the code, then use the same redirect_uri to get the token, then there is no redirect_uri_mismatch.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wasted about 4 hours on this problem.  This was the issue.  The redirect_uri I was using with my installed application to retrieve the code was "http://localhost:52800/authorize", until I matched that exactly, it gave the redirect_uri_mismatch.  Also, the 52800 was an ephemeral port that it chose to open to receive the code on.

Comment: 5 years later, still the case

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasted 2 days figuring this out.

Btw, by the time I'm writing this comment, issue still persists...

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I didnt supply from my end a redirect_uri to get authorization code but it was pre filled with some https localhost uri by google code that I used to get the authorization code. It said cut and paste the url in the browser to get the authorization code.

The redirect_uri that I am using for the access_token request is different value and one that I cut and paste from the console "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" and I do have a plain localhost preset by google in the console setting as well for redirect_uri for the installed app/other project but I don't have https web server on localhost.

Should the redirect_uri match for authorization code and access token requests? If so, what should it be for installed app/other. Should I get authorization code using "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as the redirect_uri?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The reason is in implicit google service requirements. The redirect_uri, which you send to google service (I am using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow), shouldn't be equal redirect_uri, which is set in that Auth client ID credentials record (google service). It should be equal that URI, which is marked as 'For use with requests from a browser' if there are several URIs, select that one, which sends an authCode to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Irina. For those, who don't understand:

```js
const body = new URLSearchParams({
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  client_id: '$your_id',
  client_secret: '$your_secret',
  code: '$your_code_from_initCodeClient_response',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5173'
}).toString()

const response = await axios.post(
  'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', 
  body,
  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }
)
```

And http://localhost:5173 is a line from "Authorized JavaScript origins" and my website is running on http://localhost:5173 as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those using `credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code` from `oauth2client`.  Its 5th param is set to "postmessage", instead of using the `redirect_uris` in  `client-secrets.json`. Setting the param to respective url fixes it.

Considering how [google's official guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access) suggests this, but fails to mention anything about redirect_uri param caught me off guard.

```
from oauth2client import client

credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'email'],
    serverAuthCode, None, "http://localhost:8000")
```