# Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error when trying to get access token

Tags: oauth

I am trying exchange authentication code to access token on OAuth2.

I sent a request to google using GET request, and I got a code. And now I'm trying to exchange the code to access token.

I sent request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with these arguments
using POST request

```
code=[Authentication code]
client_id=[Client ID]
client_secret=[Client Secret]
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
grant_type=authorization_code
```

But google responsed like this with 400 error

{
      "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
    }

I created Client ID on google developers console. I used type 'Installed Application'.
I also tried:
    request_uri=@://localhost:8081
    request_uri=@://localhost:8081/

(@ means http. I edited on my phone, so I couldn't insert code block for http)
But it didn't worked.

What's wrong with request?

Comment: `redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` – what is that value supposed to represent? Usually you specify an HTTP(S) URL for that parameter that the client gets redirected back to after the user authenticated with the OAuth provider …

Comment: you are sending it as a HTTP post and not a HTTP Get correct? http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: I also tried redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/. And I requested to google server with GET and I got a code, and now I'm trying to exchange this code to access token. This request must be POST.

Answer (score 1):

Check these 2 steps below

1. The redirect uri to retrieve auth code and access token should be same
2. Use the same redirect uri that you configured while creating the application, screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

apparently, both calls, the first to the auth endpoint and the second to get the token, need to use THE SAME `redirect_uri` (wth#?!)
(thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25163080/274720)